# A phrase in American English that, as a native British speaker, I may have misheard

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am a lifetime native speaker of British English and sometimes I don't recognise phrases used by North American speakers. I can be unsure whether it is an unfamiliar phrase or whether I have misunderstood because of the speakers accent.

In this instance the phrase comes from a court-case I am am following.

This is what I hear the lawyer say:

> Uh ... Did you ever use the term uh ... [inaudible] sickness. Have you
> ever heard that?
>
> [14-CA v. BRODERICK: WITNESS TESTIMONY](https://www.courttv.com/title/14-ca-v-broderick-witness-testimony/)

The words occur roughly **51 minutes** into the recording. (marked as 51:00 on the play bar under the picture). Apologies; you will get some adverts but they will eventually disappear even it seems like they might not!

**Question**

What does the male lawyer actually say?

---

**Note**

I made the above transcription. I didn't give my interpretation because I thought it would be a distraction. If you want to know what I *believe* he says then it follows below:

> Uh ... Did you ever use the term uh ... ***gray carry*** sickness. Have you ever heard that?

Comment: Sounds like what you suggested.  No guess at the spelling, though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ELU is not a transcription service

Comment: It sounds idiosyncratic and not an idiom in American English.

Comment: Maybe you could ask on a medical site for things that sound like _gray carry sickness_

Comment: This could be _Gray-Carrey sickness_, referencing the (abnormal) personality of Steve Gray, a character portrayed by Jim Carrey [[ContactMusic](https://www.contactmusic.com/jim-carrey/news/jim-carrey-tells-us-about-steve-gray-in-the-incredible-burt-wonderstone_3547552)). But so niche as to be off-topic on ELU.

Comment: It is a reference to the law firm of Gray, Cary. [The True Story of Betty Broderick’s Divorce (Oprah Daily)](https://www.oprahdaily.com/entertainment/a32479974/betty-broderick-divorce-dirty-john-true-story/)

Answer (score 1):

MetaEd commented:

> It is a reference to the law firm of Gray, Cary. [The True Story of Betty Broderick’s Divorce (Oprah Daily)](https://www.oprahdaily.com/entertainment/a32479974/betty-broderick-divorce-dirty-john-true-story/)